# Dynamic Binding Of Row Data with Column

Tags: html, angular, binding, angular5

My approach for Dynamic binding of Table Data in Angular 5.

TS:

```
    columnList = [{
           name: "info.xyz",
           title: "Xyz"
            }];
```

HTML:

```
 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let c of columnsList">
                        {{c.title}}     
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of dataList">
            <td *ngFor="let c of columnsList">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        {{data[c.name]}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The dataList variable is something I get from my API payload.
It looks like
    API:

```
{
info:{
    xyz:4
    }
}
```

I'm trying to display the row data dynamically according to the title in the column. But, html won't accept {{data[c.name]}} as c.name itself is info.xyz
But if the c.name is of a single hierarchy without a dot, it works fine as it will take data[info]. But, the API data has to be without payloads for this. ie
data[info.xyz] is not working (as in the post)

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
columnsList = [
{
  level1: "test",
  level2: "xyz",
  level3: "pqr",
  title: "Pqr"
},
{
  level1: "info",
  level2: "xyz",
  title: "Xyz"
},
{
  level1: "abc",
  title: "Abc"
}
```

];

```
dataList = [{
info: {
  xyz: 4
},
abc : 5,
test: {
  xyz : {
    pqr : 17
  }
}
```

}];

```
<table class="kruti">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let c of columnsList">
             {{c.title}}     
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of dataList">
        <td *ngFor="let c of columnsList">
            <div>
                <div>
                  <span *ngIf="c.level3">{{data[c.level1][c.level2][c.level3]}}</span>
                  <span *ngIf="c.level2 && !c.level3">{{data[c.level1][c.level2]}}</span>
                  <span *ngIf="!c.level2 && !c.level3">{{data[c.level1]}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```